# Composite key in NOT IN clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table where two columns (Invoice_Id & Invoice_line) as the primary key (Composite key). And there is another table with similar structure. I want to filter out the data from table 1 which is not in the table two.

Something similar to below query

```
SELECT * 
   FROM INVOICE_LINE T1
   WHERE T1.INVOICE_ID AND T1.LINE
   NOT IN (SELECT T2.INVOICE_ID,T2.LINE
           FROM INVOICE_LINE2
           WHERE T1.INVOICE_ID = T2.INVOICE_ID
           AND   T1.LINE       = T2.LINE
);
```

I have tried the above query but its not working properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, You can use the `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT * 

FROM 
    INVOICE_LINE T1 
        LEFT JOIN INVOICE_LINE2 T2 ON T1.INVOICE_ID = T2.INVOICE_ID
        AND   T1.LINE= T2.LINE

WHERE
    T2.INVOICE_ID IS NULL OR T2.Line IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

use not exists

```
 FROM INVOICE_LINE T1
   WHERE
   NOT exists (SELECT 1
           FROM INVOICE_LINE2
           WHERE T1.INVOICE_ID = T2.INVOICE_ID
           AND   T1.LINE       = T2.LINE
);
```

Comment: Thank you this is the easiest replacement for NOT IN

Answer (score 0):

Try below -

```
select * FROM INVOICE_LINE T1
   WHERE (T1.INVOICE_ID,T1.LINE)
   NOT IN (SELECT T2.INVOICE_ID,T2.LINE
           FROM INVOICE_LINE2)
```

OR you can use left join

```
select * FROM INVOICE_LINE T1 
left join INVOICE_LINE2 T2 on T1.INVOICE_ID = T2.INVOICE_ID
           AND   T1.LINE= T2.LINE
where T2.INVOICE_ID is null
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the [minus](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/minus.php) operator

Hence you could write the SQL as below, if the Table 2 is exactly the same

```
SELECT * FROM INVOICE_LINE T1
MINUS
SELECT * FROM INVOICE_LINE2 T2
```